# [Java][RestAssured] How to save application/octet-stream response as jpg image?

Tags: java, save, rest-assured, octetstring

I want to download images from website using RestAssured. My code:

```
Response response = given()
            .log().all()
            .cookie(cookie)
            .get(format(image_endpoint, "46581657"));
```

Endpoint returns status code 200 and image in "application/octet-stream" type. How can I save it as jpg file?

I have tried:

```
String bin = getImageResponse()
            .prettyPrint();
    saveFile("foto.jpg", bin); //this method only save string to file
```

But I cannot open jpg file. How can I save it?

Answer (score 0):

MIME type application/octet-stream consists of bytes encoded in Base64. Use [Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) class for decoding.

```
private void saveFile(String path, String octetStream) throws IOException{
    byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(octetStream);

    try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path)){
        fos.write(bytes);
    }
}
```

*I know nothing about RestAssured, so maybe there is any way provided by framework.*